# Updating angular from one 4.2.x to 4.3

Tags: angular

Angular 4.3 is just out and they got this new HttpClient replacing the HttpModule. But I happened to start with 4.2 and I'd like to tap into this new implementation.

What's the recommended way for me to update the app to 4.3?

Current dependencies are as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Not, all but some clearly needed to be upped. 
So what do I do?

`rm -rf node_modules?`

That sounds like an overkill.

Modifying the package.json ( by replacing all 4.2.4's with 4.3 ) and then running the `npm install` makes me cautious and urges me to ask before actually to do it.

I do not want to run `npm install` and then learn what happens after that the hard way. :)

Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: `npm install --save @angular/core@4.3.1` and do that for all other angular packages too

Comment: The you called "hard" way is the standard approach for updating dependencies. You can't break anything as long as you have a version control system like git or subversion which will keep your original package.json for you. Also you might want to have NPM in Version 5.x to generate a package-lock.json which makes sure every "npm install" is equal.

Comment: Andre, please post it as an answer so I can choose it as an accepted answer.

Comment: have you discovered the answer to this issue? please me know and other people too

Answer (score 0):

simply write the command
**npm update --save**

it will upgrade to latest stable version
i was also having the same requirement as yours to use HttpClient
it has updated all my project configuration files to the latest version, i dont have to do any manual work as i have read on some other post
[old package.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y45Bi.png) || 
[new package.json file after updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVyMu.png)

i got reference from Mick Lawitzke answer on github, below is the link

reference : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7162